# After upgrade to 16.04, shared libraries give segmentation fault

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, xubuntu

I have a lot of code written on ubuntu 14.04 (i386), and now, that code doesn't seem to be working on xubuntu 16.04 (amd64). I thought that this was related to some errors in my code, so I posted it on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929495). But now i installed ubuntu 14.04 in virtual machine, and that same code is working.
The problem occurs when `dlopen` is called, 14.04 is cool with it, but 16.04 gives segmentation fault.

I'm using DLang (latest DMD amd64), on xubuntu 16.04;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem, turns out, the shared library wasn't compiled right. I recompiled the source using `dmd -fPIC %FNAMES%`.